# Data Science in Law Enforcement/National Security

Tags: machine-learning

I'm a senior undergrad in the US currently, and I will be graduating this spring with BS degrees in data science and mathematics. Up to this point, I have primarily studied statistics, data analysis, and machine learning in the subjects of sports analytics, supply chain analysis, and within various economic applications as well; however, something I have been very interested in getting into for my future occupation is aiding the fields of law enforcement and/or national security with my data science skills.

I'm looking for any and all advice when it comes to breaking into this type of industry coming out of college. I understand many of you have upper-level degrees in data science, or a closely related field. Do you believe an upper-level degree is required to be successful in data science as a future career? Specifically in law enforcement or national security?

If anyone has any idea or advice on how to break into this industry in the way of data science or statistics, your advice would be much appreciated. Thank you and I hope everyone can have a great week!